# Why $s=0$ is not allowed in Elgamal signature?

Tags: elgamal-signature

In Elgamal signature scheme $\text{sig}_{k_{pr}}(x,k_E)=(r,s)$, $s=0$ is not allowed. How does this lead to finding the private key $d$?

Comment: Did you check that the signature can be verifiable?

Comment: Thanks. For verification we should have $\beta^r.r^s \bmod p=\alpha^x$, which in this particular case leads to $\alpha^{d.r+0}\neq \alpha^x$. And using hash functions will not solve this problem, is it true?

Comment: The $m$ should be already the hash of the message, otherwise, the signature space will be limited. I couldn't find a dupe for this. If you want you can write an answer to your question.

Comment: Thanks dear Henry.

Answer (score 1):

For $s=0$, we will have problem verifying the signature. For verification, we should have $\beta^r \cdot r^s=\alpha^x$. This special case, $s=0$, leads to $\beta^r \cdot r^0=\beta^r=\alpha^{d \cdot r}$ which must be equal to $\alpha^x$, i.e. $d \cdot r=x$, but $d \cdot r$ is equal for every $x$ and this have no meaning.

Comment: That is more than that. $r$ is public in the signature, then you find the $d$ :)